# Is there a way to override the property accessor methods with a custom method?

Tags: vb.net, properties, attributes, accessor

I'd like to collect some specific data when properties on my objects are accessed.

In this example, a counter would increment every time the property is read but other logic might need to be executed as well.  I'd like to intercept the gettter of the property method and so some of my own custom logic in it's place.

It appears at the moment that the property method is not inheritable in order to customize my own but maybe there is a way to declare the attribute to override the method to execute before or after the method on the property does?  Any help would be appreciated.

Sample idea:

```
Public Class MyObject
    <MyPropertyTag()>
    Property funTestValue As String

    Sub testMethod()
        Dim x = funTestValue `counter increases by one`
    End Sub
End Class

<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)>
Public Class MyPropertyTag
    Inherits System.Attribute

    Private Val
    Private _counter As Long
    Function [Get]()
        _counter += 1
        Return Val
    End Function
    Sub [Set](value)
        Me.Val = value
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the long form of the Property procedure and increment an integer property in the Get.

```
Public Class MyObject

    Public Property NumberOfTestValueAccess As Integer

    Private _funTestValue As String

    Public Property funTestValue As String

        Get
            NumberOfTestValueAccess += 1
            Return _funTestValue
        End Get

        Set(value As String)
            _funTestValue = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Testing code.

```
Private obj As New MyObject()

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    obj.funTestValue = "Hello"
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim s = obj.funTestValue
    MessageBox.Show($"The property value is {s} The number of times it was accessed is {obj.NumberOfTestValueAccess}")
End Sub
```

Comment: That would be fine if it was one value,  however I need to do this for all values on the object which could be many and the code to process would be more advanced than the counter.  I’m trying to find a solution that does not involve duplication of the underlying logic.  That’s why I’m looking for a solution that uses and attribute or can inherit the methods to do the equivalent of the property accessor.